# Why does the program increase the value of the x and the y even after they are bigger, then they should be?

Tags: c++, coordinates, move, infinity

I'm making a program, that moves a dot, from the startx, starty to endx, endy.
But it moves continuously, even after the x and the y are bigger than endx and endy.
Here is the code:

```cpp
int x, y;
            x = startx; y = starty;
            if(startx<goalx){
                if (starty < goaly) {
                    while (startx < goalx || starty < goaly) {
                        x += sqrt(2)*speedx;
                        y += sqrt(2)*speedy;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while (startx < goalx || starty > goaly) {
                        x += sqrt(2)*speedx;
                        y -= sqrt(2)*speedy;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (starty < goaly) {
                    while (startx > goalx || starty < goaly) {
                        x -= sqrt(2)*speedx;
                        y += sqrt(2)*speedy;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while (startx > goalx || starty > goaly) {
                        x -= sqrt(2)*speedx;
                        y -= sqrt(2)*speedy;
                    }
                }


            }
            cout << x << ", " << y << endl;
```

startx, starty, goalx and goaly are user inputs.

Comment: your else condition isn't working properly . The one containing loop

Comment: The else belongs to the if.

Comment: lemme check it. Please specify some values for your inputs

Comment: So if startx = 12, starty = 23, goalx = 78 and goaly = 89, then it works.
But when , fe : goaly = 22, then it doesn't

Comment: The conditions of the loops test values of `startx`, `goalx`, `starty`, and `goaly`.   The bodies of the loops only change values of `x` and `y`, but never change the variables tested in the loop conditions.   The loops are therefore infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control structures depend on `startx` and `starty` but these are never changing. Supposedly `x` and `y` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int x, y;
    x = startx; y = starty;
    int xInc = sqrt(2) * speedx;
    int yInc = sqrt(2) * speedy;
    if(x < goalx && y < goaly)
    {
        while(x < goalx || y < goaly)
        {
            x += xInc;
            y += yInc;
        }
    }
    else if(x < goalx && y > goaly)
    {
        while(x < goalx || y > goaly)
        {
            x += xInc;
            y -= yInc;
        }
    }
    else if(x > goalx && y < goaly)
    {
        while(x > goalx || y < goaly)
        {
            x -= xInc;
            y += yInc;
        }
    }
    else if(x > goalx && y > goaly)
    {
        while(x > goalx || y > goaly)
        {
            x -= xInc;
            y -= yInc;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a 'cout << x << "," << y' at the end, and it doesn't give any output. It still stuck in the while loops.

Comment: Yes add it bro, you have to intialize speedx, speedy, goalx, goaly, startx, starty....and if it doesn't work then share whole code instead of code-fragment.

Comment: The whole code is very very long...
(starts and goals are user inputs)

Comment: then do debugging.. use any debugger, or use cout statements in between to know, where it going wrong.